# MS Excel - remove zeros from comma separated list produced by CSV function

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with a tricky function that I am using to generate a column separated list from a table in MS Excel.

My data is as follows:

```
Column A       B         C        D        E
John           Bill      0        0        0
               Steve     0        0        0 
                         0        0        0
                         0        0        0
```

I have created a VBA function that will will generate the following lists (each in a single cell):

```
John, 
Bill, Steve, 
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

I am stuck because I do nto know how to edit my function so it will nto include the columns with zeros in.

My function is as follows:

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    For Each Entry In myRange

        If Not Entry.Value = "" Then

            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & Entry.Value & ", "

        End If

    Next
    csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)


End Function
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

P.S. I have already tried changing the line “If Not Entry.Value = “” - to - If Not Entry.Value = 0 OR Entry.Value = “” – unfortunately, it does not work!

Thanks,

Ollie

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
If Not Entry.Value = "" Then
    If Not Entry.Value = 0 Then
        csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & Entry.Value & ", "
    end If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    For Each Entry In myRange

        If (Not Entry.Value = "") and (Not Entry.Value = "0") Then

            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & Entry.Value & ", "

        End If

    Next
    csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)


End Function
```

The cells are probably in string format

Comment: changed the statement. Pretty sure hes got the cells in string format.